# Matrices inner produce

Tags: matrices, summation

I had a question about matrices.

Why is $1^T*X = \sum X_i $ ?  [ Here X is also a matrix]

Basically, why is $1^T*X $ the sum of all the elements in the matrix X.

Comment: It depends. If $1$ is a matrix $n\times 1$ with $1$s as entries, and $X$ is a matrix $n\times 1$, then yes.

Comment: What is $X_i$? If $X$ is a column vector and $X_i$ are its entries, then yes, it's basically the sum of all elements of $X$. If $X_i$ are columns of $X$, then the equation is true but apparently, $\sum X_i$ is not the sum of all elements of $X$ (depending on what that would mean though). In any case, writing down components of $1^TX$ would help.